# bilinear form only positive or negative

Tags: proof-verification, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form, positive-definite

Let $f$ be a definite, symmetric bilinear form.

Show that $f$ is positive or negative.

---

<s>Consider the quadratic form $q(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^2$, then the polar form assocaited to $q$ is symmetric, definite but negative and positive.
Is there a problem with the statement of the problem ?</s>

EDIT:
I attempt to prove this result:

Let $x,\tilde y$ such that $q(x)>0$ and $q(\tilde y)<0$ where $q$ is the quadratic form associated to $f$.

Let $\lambda$ such that $y=\lambda \tilde y$ is such that $f(x,y-x)=0$.
Note that $q(y)<0$.

We have for $t\in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
q(x+t(y-x))=q(x)+t^2q(y-x)
$$
and we obtain:
$q(y-x)<-q(x)<0$

By continuity of $f$, there exists $t\in (0,1)$ such that $q(x+t(y-x))=0$.
(This $t$ could be such that $x+t(y-x)=0$).

But, when $t\to \infty$, $q(x+t(y-x))\to -\infty$, so it means that $q$ has to for two different value of $t$ which is absurd.

Finally $q$ is of constant sign.

Any toughts about this proof?

DO you have simpler alternative proof for this statement ?

Comment: Why would your $f$ be definite?

Comment: I mean your assertion "the polar form associated to $q$ is [...] definite"

Comment: I don't understand. The form $x^2 + y^2 - z^2$ is called "indefinite"

Comment: ok yeah the quadratic form is not definite

Answer (score 1):

I found what seems to be the definition at [Associated Bilinear Form to Q (Quadratic Form)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631402/associated-bilinear-form-to-q-quadratic-form)

The short version: given a quadratic form, create the matrix $H$ which is the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives.

Given column vectors $x,y:$ the original quadratic form applied to $x$ is given by
$$  (1/2) x^T H x  $$
The bilinear form applied to $x,y$ is 
$$  (1/2) x^T H y  =  (1/2) y^T H x  $$